# Captured image doesn't show up in ImageView

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview

in my app I need to capture image and show up in imageview and then I will post it to server. But I'm having a problem, the captured image is not showing in imageview. Here is my code:

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull(data.getExtras()).get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        assert thumbnail != null;
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bytes);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/storage/emulated/0/Download/"
                + new Date().getTime(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (photoMekanik) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            photoMekanik = false;
        } else if (photoElektonik) {
            imageView2.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            photoElektonik = false;
        }
    }
```

Image is stored, but I want to access directly after capturing the image. What I'm missing here.

Comment: your condition doesn't handle else. Check `photoMekanik` or `photoElektronik` else condition

Comment: I have two imageviews in my activity, for each of them I will show different images.

Comment: can you guarantee that condition achieve?

Comment: yes, this condition is ok. I only want to show captured image to imageview